# Program works when I print the value out, but not when I don't

Tags: c, printf

I have the following program that is checking for substrings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int checkSubstring(char string[], char sub[]) {
    int k, j = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=8; i++) {
         if(sub[k] == string[i]) {
            j = j + 1;
            k = k + 1;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        else {
            j = i;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", count);

    if(count == 3) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I'm testing my program and it seems to only work when I do `printf("%d", count);`.

For example, If I test the string "Schoolbus" against "bus", it should return TRUE because bus is a substring in Schoolbus. However, it only returns true when the printf statement is put in place. When I comment it out, it returns FALSE. I have no idea why it would be doing this... I use 8 in my loop to test against the length of schoolbus (9). I'm also checking if count is == 3, because if the strings match I can count it up to the length of the substring. If the count does not match length, then we know it isn't a match.

Comment: `k` isn't initialized, so `sub[k]` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: Wait, I thought I could do int k,j = 0;? I swear I saw that somewhere

Comment: you can "do" it .. it initializes `j` to 0, but `k` is unitialized, so it will take on whatever value is at that place in memory, which is completely unpredictable. You need to say `k = 0` too if you want it start at 0. And better make sure `string` and `sub` are at least 10 chars long.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @yano, `k` isn't initialized, so `sub[k]` has undefined behaviour.

To initialize both `j` and `k` to zero, you could either do

```c
int j = 0, k = 0;
```

or

```c
int j, k;
j = k = 0;
```

but **not**

```c
int k, j = 0;
```